# How to capture a command or keyboard-shortcuts in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm developing an app for Mac OSX in Xcode 5.1 and I want to make an action when a user presses the combination of `cmd+E` (for instance).

This is my working code I have so far:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    //If the key is X just closes the window
    if ([theEvent.characters.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"X"]) {
        [self close];
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to open an app by pressing such combination, but I haven't found a way to capture the `cmd` key, just the `E`.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want them globally you can try **DDHotKey**

https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey

If you want to activate them locally you can use Carbon Framework import it to your project,

You can get the entire keyCode list on Events.h (inside carbon framework)

for instance if you want to trigger locally (in your app) an specific action by pressing left key button you can do like this

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    if (theEvent.keyCode == kVK_LeftArrow) {  NSLog("left key pressed"); }

}
```